# Inserting ID through PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I am trying to pass an ID from one page to another. I am getting that ID in the other page and I am trying to insert that ID in a different table. Consider that I have one table 'question' and I am taking the question ID from this table and passing it to another page. I am trying to store this ID in another table 'answer' in the next page. Here are the codes-

The First page-

```
<?php

                require('connect_db.php');
                $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM question";
                $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$strSQL);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                   echo "<a href='AddAnswer.php?IsEdit=1&ID=" .$row['qu_title']. "'><h3 style='font-family: Georgia;margin-left: 3.8%'>".$row['qu_title']."</h3></a>";
                   echo "<h5 style='font-family: Georgia;margin-left: 3.8%'>".$row['qu_text']."</h5>";
                   echo "<hr>";
                  }

                mysqli_close($conn);

            ?>
```

The Second Page-

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require('connect_db.php');
   if (isset($_SESSION['email']) and $_SESSION['loggedin'] == "true") {

  global $id;
$id = ($_GET['ID']);
//echo $id;
if (isset($_POST['answer'])) 
{
    $answer=$_POST['answer'];
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO answer(qu_id,ans_text)VALUES 
    ('$id','$answer')");
    header("location:Main.php?msg=success");
    mysqli_close($conn);
   }
 } 

 else {
     header("location:Login.php?msg=try");
  }
?>
```

But there seems to be problem in inserting this ID. Can anyone figure out this problem?

Comment: could you clarify a bit what the problem is? Do you get an error message?

Comment: You probably want to add proper space in "INSERT INTO answer(qu_id,ans_text)VALUES" unless it was a typo.

Comment: @Burki I am not getting an error message. But the data i.e the ID does not get Inserted in the 'answer' table.

Comment: @HarshaKuchampudi I have tried Inserting other values. For example- by setting $qu_id="1" or something and it gets inserted. So I guess it is not that mistake

Comment: @HarshaKuchampudi Yes the database is getting connected as the other columns in table 'answer' is getting filled except for the ID column.

Comment: When you run $qu_id=$row['qu_title']; what value is stored in $qu_id if any? If may just be the way you are accessing the results of the database query.

Comment: @HarshaKuchampudi Actually my qu_title is the ID.So by doing $qu_id=$row['qu_title']; I am storing the ID in $qu_id. When I echoed $qu_id I got the same.

Comment: So, you can confirm that a value is actually being stored in $qu_id when the script is run? In which case it must be the query itself... Let me take a look

Comment: @HarshaKuchampudi I have updated the second page in this Question to some simpler method. Please check for better clarification :) .

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the value from first page to second page as get method. But in second page you're using that $_POST['ID'] to insert the value. You can use $_GET['ID'] or $_REQUEST['ID']

Comment: You mean this?
$id = ($_GET['ID']);
 if (isset($_GET['answer'])) 
 {}

Comment: what you get when displaying $id

Comment: I get the ID which is passed from the first page. But the problem is this value is not getting inserted in the 'answer' table!

Comment: try to insert value as 1 in that table. If it was inserted then use the prepared statement

Comment: Yeah I have already tried that! "1" is getting inserted when I set $id="1" manually! But the original value in $id is not getting inserted!

Comment: ok then the id was string not a integer field right? Just try with prepared statement to insert the value. maybe it will help you

Comment: Yes It is a string and in the database that field is set to VARCHAR!

Comment: rather use like this mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO answer(qu_id,ans_text) VALUES 
    (" . $id . "," . $answer. ")");

Comment: I tried this and now even the other values are not getting Inserted!

Comment: try this one: $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO answer(qu_id, ans_text) VALUES(?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $id, $answer);
$stmt->execute(); If have luck this will work

Comment: It is giving this error- 'Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object'

Comment: $mysqli->prepare($conn,  your query) try this one

Comment: Same error! And two warnings-
Undefined index: ID
Undefined variable: mysqli

Comment: remove the $ symbol from mysqli and try it

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: "INSERT INTO answer(qu_id,ans_text)VALUES 
  ('$id','$answer')"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have POST and GET in same code block. Assuming that the form/php script is also returning values in the GET format in which case, either you should get the ID first and post the answer and ID to second page. or pass the answer and ID through get method. However, it is possible to use both GET and POST if the form/php script is returning POST data and the URL has additional GET data encoded.

Comment: `You cannot have POST and GET in same code block.` Yes you can. Perhaps you could clarify this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your first page has this

> ```
> echo "<a href='AddAnswer.php?IsEdit=1&ID=" .$row['qu_title']. "'><h3 style='font-family: Georgia;margin-left: 3.8%'>".$row['qu_title']."</h3></a>";
> ```

Which will result in a link that looks like this:

```
AddAnswer.php?IsEdit=1&ID=<qu_title>
```

If the user clicks on that link to bring up your second page, there will be no POST variables available (nothing was POSTed), and the values `IsEdit` and `ID` available for GET.

In your second page though you are trying to get a POST variable called `answer`:

> ```
> if (isset($_POST['answer']))
> ```

But this has never been set.

I suggest you read up about POST and GET, and then probably change the references to `$_POST` in your second page to `$_GET`, and make sure you set the value for `answer` in the HREF of the link in the first page, e.g.:

> ```
> echo "<a href='AddAnswer.php?IsEdit=1&ID=" .$row['qu_title']. "&answer=$answer'><h3 style='font-family: Georgia;margin-left: 3.8%'>".$row['qu_title']."</h3></a>";
> ```

Comment: &answer=$answer. But I do not have the value of $answer in first page! I am taking value from a textbox in Second page that's why the _POST method!

Comment: You'll need to show us your entire code then, at the moment you've not shown a textbox or how you intend to get the data from it. I assume then that the process is something like `[Server: display first page] -> [User: click on link] -> [Server: display second page with textbox] -> [User: submit form] -> [Server: handle submit]`

Comment: @SaikatMajumdar Then I'll need to see more of your code before I can help - at the moment it looks like the problem is the data isn't being POSTed but I can't tell anymore until I see the code.

Comment: Along with this there is HTML. That is quite big to be posted here and it may seem clumsy. I do not think that html code is affecting this one!

Comment: No, but you've confirmed that the server is supposed to respond three times in a user journey, but you've only shown PHP for two 'pages'.